# Is it an act of kufr to watch a movie wanting a wizard to use his magical powers?

Tags: shirk, sihr, kufr, movies

I was once watching a movie where the main character was a wizard. The movie depicted this wizard in a way which showed him to be good. In the plot the wizard took a vow never to use his powers. But I started hoping that he would use his powers to defeat the antagonist as most people do when they are watching movies of this sort. Is this an act of kufr by approval of magic?

Comment: It is an act of kufr to believe that a wizard has any power to do sonething without Allahs help.